# How can I use ".call()" method in a javascript function and why does it have a "null" value?

Tags: javascript

So basically why do I have to use this kind of method in these kind of situations in particular?

```
function Example(callback) {  
    // What's the purpose of both 'call()' and 'null'?  
    callback.call(null, "Hello") 
}  

Exemple(function(callback) {  
    alert();
})
```

I've figured it out this syntax in a open project code but I haven't found out why it works yet.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) in this situation. `call()` is used when you need to set the value of `this` in a function. If you aren't doing that, just call the function like you would any other function. For example:

```js
function Example(callback) {  
    // call the function passed in
    callback("Hello") 
    // this also works, but there's no benefit here
    // because the callback doesn't care about `this`
    // callback.call(null, "Hello") 
}  

// pass a callback function to Example
Example(function(text) {  
   console.log(text);
})
```

You would use `call` in situations where the callback function needs a value for `this`. For example:

```js
function Example(callback) { 
    let person = {name: "Mark"} 
    // set this in the callback to the person object 
    // and the execute it with the argument "Howdy"
    callback.call(person, "Howdy") 
}  

Example(function(greeting) {  
   // the callback function depends on having this.name defined
   console.log(greeting, this.name);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks pointless at the first glance, however, there might be valid reasons for this syntax, for example:

- the callback relies explicitly on `this` being `null` and not some global default
- the callback is not necessarily a function, it can be a "function-alike" object that provides a `.call` method
- `callback.call(...` is used consistently through the application, no matter if `this` is needed or not